# Duas bolinhas de gude e um prédio de 100 andares

Tags: algoritmo

Pergunta clássica de entrevistas de emprego...

Você recebe duas bolinhas de gude (berlindes), é informado que elas irão se quebrar quando caírem de uma certa altura (e presumivelmente não sofrer dano se caírem abaixo dessa altura), e é solicitado a encontrar o andar mais alto a partir do qual você pode deixar cair uma bolinha sem quebrá-la, da forma mais eficiente possível.

Informações adicionais:

- Você deve encontrar o andar correto (não um intervalo possível).
- É garantido que as duas bolinhas quebram no mesmo andar.
- Assuma que a demora para mudar de andar é zero - somente o número de quedas de bolinhas conta.
- Assuma que o andar correto está distribuído aleatoriamente no prédio.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547/two-marbles-and-a-100-story-building)

Comment: Discordo do fechamento. Este caso me parece ser um problema conceitual sobre algoritmos (desntro do escopo do site) e nele eu vejo os critérios mínimos de qualidade e detalhamento. Acredito que esta pergunta é objetiva e clara.

Comment: Creio tb que se refira ao concurso https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7516/8063

Comment: O jeito que eu conheço que faça o mínimo de lançamentos é a busca binária. Mas aí seriam 7 lançamentos e portanto 7 bolas quebradas... Talvez uma busca que comece na posição 1 e, na próxima busca, dobre o número da posição, até a bolinha quebrar. Depois inicia uma busca sequencial entre o último ponto que não quebrou e o que quebrou...

Comment: Pensando aqui rapidamente (pode ser que eu tenha desconsiderado algo, não elaborei demais) Basicamente faz um loop de 1 a 100 com step 2, ao quebrar, testa o andar logo abaixo para determinar se é no par ou no impar. Se fossem 3 bolinhas, seria 1 a 100 step 4, gastando uma delas no meio, e a terceira pra fazer a "busca binaria". Se fossem 4 bolinhas, seria step 8, e assim por diante (a primeira sempre numa busca linear equivalente ao intervalo exponencial da busca binária das seguintes)

Comment: @Bacco tinha pensado exatamente isso também e estava analisando se não conseguiria "tirar proveito" dos steps na segunda bolinha também.

Comment: @Bacco, no pior caso você tem 51 testes, no melhor 1. Creio que dá para fazer melhor, com um pior caso de 20 testes

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado como comentei, foi um pensamento rápido assim que li (tanto que nem parei pra elaborar resposta, pois geralmente "se contentar com a primeira idéia" está longe de ser coisa de bom programador). O importante é que as respostas oficial sejam boas, e é o caso da sua :D

Answer (score 5):

Fiz um teste aqui, numa ideia semelhante à do @Bacco. Consegui uma média de 11 tentativas, sendo o melhor caso 2 arremessos e o pior 20 arremessos.

Eu implementei a resolução do @Bacco, porém os resultados foram muito ruins. Média de 27 tentativas, sendo o melhor caso 2 arremessos e o pior 52.

---

Antes de entrar no mérito da solução, eu primeiro fiz um testador de soluções, que vou explicar aqui.

Um jogo, nesse caso, é configurado com a quantidade de bolinhas que você tem para destruir, a quantidade de andares disponível e o andar resposta. Segui aqui uma convenção de que a numeração dos andares começa em 1. Então, para saber qual seria a melhor solução, resolvi testar para **todas** as combinações possíveis do jogo.

Então, como minha área de *expertise* é Java, fiz o testador em Java mesmo. O jogo é dividido em 2 classes: uma que configura o jogo e permite criar uma instância, e outra com o jogo real, mantendo inclusive quantas bolinhas ainda restam para se jogar (lança uma exceção caso você gaste todas as bolinhas), quantos lançamentos você fez etc. A ideia de ter a separação é poder usar o mesmo "cenário de jogo" em dois resolvedores distintos.

Assim, eu tenho a classe `LancaBolinhas` que se preocupa em criar o cenário de lançamento de bolinhas:

```java
public class LancaBolinhas {

    private int tentativas;
    private int andares;
    private int andarResposta;

    public LancaBolinhas(int tentativas, int andares, int andarResposta) {
        this.tentativas = tentativas;
        this.andares = andares;
        this.andarResposta = andarResposta;

        if (andarResposta <= 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Parâmetro 'andarResposta' precisa ser estritamente positivo");
        }

        if (andarResposta > andares) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Parâmetro 'andarResposta' precisa ser menor ou igual ao parâmetro 'andares'");
        }

        if (tentativas <= 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Parâmetro 'tentativas' precisa ser estritamente positivo");
        }
    }

    public JogoBolinhas criaJogo() {
        return new JogoBolinhas(tentativas, andares, andarResposta);
    }
}
```

E a classe `JogoBolinhas`, que por sua vez tem quantas estatísticas foram feitas, se o resolvedor já tentou chutar uma resposta, se ainda tem bolinhas disponíveis para jogar etc:

```java
public class JogoBolinhas {

    private int tentativasRestantes;
    private int andares;
    private int andarResposta;
    private boolean jahChutou = false;
    private boolean respostaCerta = false;
    private int lancamentosRealizados = 0;

    public JogoBolinhas(int tentativas, int andares, int andarResposta) {
        this.tentativasRestantes = tentativas;
        this.andares = andares;
        this.andarResposta = andarResposta;
    }

    public int getAndares() {
        return andares;
    }

    public int getTentativasRestantes() {
        return tentativasRestantes;
    }

    public int getLancamentosRealizados() {
        return lancamentosRealizados;
    }

    public boolean isRespostaCerta() {
        return respostaCerta;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param andarTeste
     * @return Se a bolinha continua intacta; ie, andar de teste menor do que o andar de resposta
     */
    public boolean testaAndar(int andarTeste) {
        if (tentativasRestantes <= 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Esgotou o número de tentativas");
        }
        lancamentosRealizados++;
        if (andarTeste > andares) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Você não pode jogar uma bolinha além do último andar");
        }
        if (andarTeste >= andarResposta) {
            tentativasRestantes--;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean tentaResposta(int andarTeste) {
        if (jahChutou) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Só pode fazer um único chute");
        }
        tentativasRestantes = 0;
        jahChutou = true;
        return respostaCerta = (andarTeste == andarResposta);
    }
}
```

Eu defini um resolvedor como sendo uma interface funcional que estende de `Consumer<JogoBolinhas>` (já que não preciso mais do que isso, as informações da partida eu obtenho depois do próprio `JogoBolinhas`) e permite definir qual o nome do resolvedor (por conveniência):

```java
public interface LancaBolinhasResolver extends Consumer<JogoBolinhas> {
    default String nomeResolvedor() {
        return "Novo resolvedor";
    }
}
```

Em cima disso, eu criei uma pequena `Main` para gerar todos os 100 jogos possíveis e, em cima de um conjunto de resolvedores, testar os resolvedores e tirar algumas estatísticas deles:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int andares = 100;
        int tentativas = 2;
        
        List<LancaBolinhas> jogosPossiveis = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
                .mapToObj(r -> new LancaBolinhas(tentativas, andares, r))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        testaJogos(resolvedores(), jogosPossiveis);
    }

    private static void testaJogos(List<LancaBolinhasResolver> resolvedores, List<LancaBolinhas> jogosPossiveis) {
        for (LancaBolinhasResolver resolvedor: resolvedores) {
            IntSummaryStatistics st = jogosPossiveis.stream()
                    .map(LancaBolinhas::criaJogo)
                    .peek(resolvedor)
                    .filter(JogoBolinhas::isRespostaCerta)
                    .mapToInt(JogoBolinhas::getLancamentosRealizados)
                    .summaryStatistics();
            int soma = (int) st.getSum();
            int count = (int) st.getCount();
            int maior = st.getMax();
            int menor = st.getMin();
            double avg = st.getAverage();
            
            System.out.println(String.format("[RESULTADO] [%s] foram encontrados %d resultados de %d testes, num total de %d lançamentos; média de lançamentos: %f; maior quantidade de lançamentos: %d; menor quantidade de lançamentos: %d", resolvedor.nomeResolvedor(), count, jogosPossiveis.size(), soma, avg, maior, menor));
        }
    }

    // retorna os resolvedores que estão sendo testados
    private static List<LancaBolinhasResolver> resolvedores() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

---

A solução do @Bacco é basicamente tentar de 2 em 2 até achar a resposta. A minha solução semelhante foi dividir em blocos de igual tamanho e, então, tentar 1 a 1 nesse bloco qual seria o andar adequado, de modo que a quantidade de blocos seja igual à de tentativas 1 a 1 dentro desse bloco. Daí, cheguei em blocos de 10.

> Se fossem `k` bolinhas em um universo de `p^k` andares, a lógica é bem semelhante a essa apresentada, porém recursiva.
>
> Eu dividiria em blocos de tamanho `p^(k-1)` para a primeira bolinha, de tal modo que eu garanta um número `0 <= n < p` tal que a bolinha arremessada de `n*p^(k-1)` não quebre, porém que quebre quando arremessada de `(n+1)*p^(k-1)`. Depois, dentro desse bloco de tamanho `p^(k-1)`, a segunda bolinha seja usada para procurar em qual bloco de tamanho `p^(k-2)` quebre, achando um `0 <= m < p` tal que `m*p^(k-2) + n*p^(k-1)` não quebre e que `(m+1)*p^(k-2) + n*p^(k-1)` quebre. Faz isso recursivo até que eu tenha blocos de tamanho `p` na `k-1`-ésima bolinha, e a `k`-ésima bolinha eu tente de 1 em 1 as `p` opções restantes.
>
> Pelas minha estimativas, essa solução teria um total de `p*k` tentativas no pior caso, e `k` tentativas no melhor caso.

Retirando pela definição dos tamanhos dos blocos, o algoritmo a grosso modo é o mesmo. Eu chamei esse algoritmo comum de `LinearResolver` e ele é (para `incrementoTentativa` e `startPoint` definidos como o tamanho do bloco e o primeiro andar de teste respectivamente) basicamente assim:

```java
public void accept(JogoBolinhas jogo) {
    OptionalInt ultimaCasaTestadaComSucesso = OptionalInt.empty();
    int casaTeste = startPoint;
    int casaLimite;
    OptionalInt casaResposta = OptionalInt.empty();

    while (true) {
        boolean bolinhaIntacta = jogo.testaAndar(casaTeste);

        depuracao(String.format("[%s] jogou a bolinha do %d andar, e ela %s", nomeResolvedor(), casaTeste, bolinhaIntacta? "continua intacta": "quebrou"));

        if (bolinhaIntacta) {
            ultimaCasaTestadaComSucesso = OptionalInt.of(casaTeste);
            casaTeste += incrementoTentativa;
        } else {
            casaLimite = casaTeste;
            break;
        }
        
        if (casaTeste > jogo.getAndares()) {
            casaLimite = jogo.getAndares();
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = ultimaCasaTestadaComSucesso.orElse(0) + 1; i <= casaLimite; i++) {
        boolean bolinhaIntacta = jogo.testaAndar(i);

        depuracao(String.format("[%s] jogou a bolinha do %d andar, e ela %s", nomeResolvedor(), i, bolinhaIntacta? "continua intacta": "quebrou"));
        
        if (!bolinhaIntacta) {
            casaResposta = OptionalInt.of(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    casaResposta.ifPresent(jogo::tentaResposta);
}
```

No caso, defini as classes `JeffResolver`, `BaccoResolver` e `BaccoResolver2` (porque fiquei em dúvida se começava no andar 1 ou no andar 2 pelo algoritmo do @Bacco) estendendo de `LinearResolver`, passando o `incrementoTentativa` (e o `startPoint` quando for o caso) na construção do super-objeto.

A classe `LinearResolver` é isso, na sua versão completa:

```java
public class LinearResolver implements LancaBolinhasResolver {

    public static boolean printDepuracao = false;

    private final int incrementoTentativa;
    private final int startPoint;

    public LinearResolver(int incrementoPrimeiraTentativa) {
        this.incrementoTentativa = incrementoPrimeiraTentativa;
        startPoint = incrementoPrimeiraTentativa;
    }

    public LinearResolver(int incrementoPrimeiraTentativa, int startPoint) {
        this.incrementoTentativa = incrementoPrimeiraTentativa;
        this.startPoint = startPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public String nomeResolvedor() {
        return String.format("Resolvedor linear, começando de %d e saltando %d andares", startPoint, incrementoTentativa);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(JogoBolinhas jogo) {
        OptionalInt ultimaCasaTestadaComSucesso = OptionalInt.empty();
        int casaTeste = startPoint;
        int casaLimite;
        OptionalInt casaResposta = OptionalInt.empty();

        while (true) {
            boolean bolinhaIntacta = jogo.testaAndar(casaTeste);

            depuracao(String.format("[%s] jogou a bolinha do %d andar, e ela %s", nomeResolvedor(), casaTeste, bolinhaIntacta? "continua intacta": "quebrou"));

            if (bolinhaIntacta) {
                ultimaCasaTestadaComSucesso = OptionalInt.of(casaTeste);
                casaTeste += incrementoTentativa;
            } else {
                casaLimite = casaTeste;
                break;
            }
            
            if (casaTeste > jogo.getAndares()) {
                casaLimite = jogo.getAndares();
                break;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = ultimaCasaTestadaComSucesso.orElse(0) + 1; i <= casaLimite; i++) {
            boolean bolinhaIntacta = jogo.testaAndar(i);

            depuracao(String.format("[%s] jogou a bolinha do %d andar, e ela %s", nomeResolvedor(), i, bolinhaIntacta? "continua intacta": "quebrou"));
            
            if (!bolinhaIntacta) {
                casaResposta = OptionalInt.of(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        
        casaResposta.ifPresent(i -> tentaResposta(i, jogo));
    }
    
    private void tentaResposta(int andarChute, JogoBolinhas jogo) {
        boolean resultadoChute = jogo.tentaResposta(andarChute);
        
        depuracao(String.format("[%s] chutando do %d andar, em um total de %d lançamentos, resultado? %s", nomeResolvedor(), andarChute, jogo.getLancamentosRealizados(), resultadoChute? "acertou": "errou"));
    }

    private static void depuracao(String str) {
        if (printDepuracao) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

A classe `JeffResolver`, então, é simplesmente isso:

```java
public class JeffResolver extends LinearResolver {

    public JeffResolver() {
        super(10);
    }

    @Override
    public String nomeResolvedor() {
        return "Jeff resolver";
    }
}
```

A classe `BaccoResolver`:

```java
public class BaccoResolver extends LinearResolver {

    public BaccoResolver() {
        super(2);
    }

    @Override
    public String nomeResolvedor() {
        return "Bacco resolver (começando no 2)";
    }
}
```

E, finalmente, a `BaccoResolver2`:

```java
public class BaccoResolver2 extends LinearResolver {

    public BaccoResolver2() {
        super(2, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String nomeResolvedor() {
        return "Bacco resolver (começando no 1)";
    }
}
```

No teste para comparar as 3 implementações do `LancaBolinhasResolver`, escrevi o seguinte no método estático `resolvedores`:

```java
private static List<LancaBolinhasResolver> resolvedores() {
    return Arrays.asList(new JeffResolver(), new BaccoResolver(), new BaccoResolver2());
}
```

O resultado obtido foi:

```
[RESULTADO] [Jeff resolver] foram encontrados 100 resultados de 100 testes, num total de 1100 lançamentos; média de lançamentos: 11,000000; maior quantidade de lançamentos: 20; menor quantidade de lançamentos: 2
[RESULTADO] [Bacco resolver (começando no 2)] foram encontrados 100 resultados de 100 testes, num total de 2700 lançamentos; média de lançamentos: 27,000000; maior quantidade de lançamentos: 52; menor quantidade de lançamentos: 2
[RESULTADO] [Bacco resolver (começando no 1)] foram encontrados 100 resultados de 100 testes, num total de 2748 lançamentos; média de lançamentos: 27,480000; maior quantidade de lançamentos: 52; menor quantidade de lançamentos: 2
```

---

Não satisfeito em encontrar uma resposta com boa média (11), resolvi testar em força bruta qual seria o melhor `LinearResolver` para um problema limitado a 100 andares. Então, criei todas as opções de `incrementoTentativa` de 1 até 100. Assim, o método `resolvedores` ficou assim:

```java
private static List<LancaBolinhasResolver> resolvedoresBruteForce() {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).mapToObj(LinearResolver::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

A resposta com melhor média foi com o `incrementoTentativa == 12`, dando média de 10.98, sendo o melhor caso 2 arremessos e o pior 20 arremessos. Com `incrementoTentativa == 11` também deu um resultado melhor do que a solução dividindo em grupos de 10, com a média de 10.99 (e a mesma quantidade de arremessos no melhor/pior caso).

Foi interessante notar que, considerando `i*k == 100`, o resultado obtido para `incrementoTentativa == i` é exatamente o mesmo do que o para `incrementoTentativa == k`, reforçando a tese de que a raiz quadrada do número de andares está próximo da solução ótima quando se tem apenas 2 bolinhas.

---

Eu não testei para outros comportamentos (como buscar pela potência de 2 mais próxima do andar correto que a bolinha não quebre, como sugerido em meu primeiro comentário), porém creio que a solução de grupos iguais à raiz quadrada do número de andares possui uma melhor média de toda sorte. Nesse busca pelas potencias de 2, o pior caso possível seria quando a resposta fosse 64, pois seriam feitos 7 lançamentos para determinar que a resposta está no intervalo `(32, 64]` e, então, mais 31 lançamentos para achar a resposta, totalizando 38 lançamentos. O pior caso é pior do que o pior caso para `LinearResolver` com incremento de 10, a média também *parece* (não computei, apenas estimativa mesmo) ser significativamente pior.

Comment: +1, parece ótimo. Só não precisava dar tanto destaque pra comparação com a minha, que sequer era resposta, e sim a primeira bobeira que veio na cabeça :P

Comment: +1 também, mas a resposta no SOen dá 14. E agora Batman?

Comment: @Piovezan , estou pensando em outra resposta usando mochila... mas essa é uma boa resposta e fácil de extrapolar para outros casos (andares/bolinhas disponíveis), e também funciona como heurística para limitar o máximo da busca bruta. Mas ainda estou pensando no assunto, não tenho algo pronto ainda

Comment: Está de parabéns pela resposta!